# how to add javascript code to newly create window head from javascript file

Tags: javascript

I am doing a project where I want to open new window using `window.open()` from my js file and add javascript code to newly created window. Anyone know how to do it. I tried the following code to alert in new window. But not working

```
var mywindow = window.open('', '', 'scrollbars=1,height=600,width=600');
mywindow.document.write("<html><head><title>Patient Data</title>");
mywindow.document.write("</head><body>");
mywindow.document.write("Test");
mywindow.document.write("</body>");
mywindow.document.write("<script type='text/javascript'> alert('HIiii'); </script>");
mywindow.document.write("</html>");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Code works. Is you browser blocking popup windows ?

Comment: Which part of your code doesn't work? The `window.open()` or the `window.alert()`?

Comment: Why dont you keep your HTML page in separate file, and load it in that newly created window ?